# Can anyone help me about command line parameters in a WinForms application?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem understanding command line arguments in VB.NET. Need help from anyone who understands it.

This is for my app. What I wanted is when app is started with switch *-U* or any other defined parameter, open another form with progressbar.

I have created and defined new form with update functionality, but one thing missing - reaction on command line arguments.

This is for my new app running on Windows in separate folder (not in Program Files), where I want to use auto update function.

Comment: I am totally failing to understand what you are trying to ask

Comment: Have a look into something like [NDesk.Options](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NDesk.Options/0.2.1) to handle this.

Comment: Sorry, I also don't know what you're asking. Maybe get a different translator, update your question with English, and also include some code. Then, people maybe able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite simple to do.

When your application loads, get a list of the command line variables, then iterate through them and look for the one you want, then act accordingly:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim arguments As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

    For Each a In arguments 'loop through the args in case there are multiple
        Select Case a.ToUpper 'compare in uppercase if you don't care how the user enters it.
            Case "-U"
                'the -U argument was found, set a flag, or perform an action, or otherwise act accordingly.
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

I always put it in a select case, because in my apps, I may have multiple arguments and I loop through them all and set properties accordingly.  In a select case, it's easy to add other parameters later.  You can easily add a case else in the event you want to throw up an 'invalid argument' message.

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=netframework-4.8

The example is in C#, but the principle is the same... use GetCommandlineArgs which returns a string array with the command line args that your app was started with.

Comment: The example is also in VB.  There's a dropdown near the top of the page (to the right of the breadcrumb path) to select language.

Comment: That link cant help me. I need working code example.

Comment: Of course the link can help you! it has a working code example right on the page!  Also that way you'll understand what is happening.  Just a friendly note, you're coming across as a bit agressive/unfriendly while asking for help.  Not a great combination.

Comment: @Craig I was wondering where the VB examples went! There used to be selections right above the code samples. Thanks M$!

Comment: Sorry for little agressive content. I really needed answer for my question more than week. Next time I make more friendly atmosphere :-)